# Getting "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname" error when testing API using Postman

Tags: rest, postman, httprequest, hostname, web-api-testing

I'm currently trying to test an API using Postman, but I'm encountering an error that says "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname." The API endpoint I'm testing is a simple GET request that returns the API version. Here are the details:

Request:

```
GET /HitTest3/api/hit?api_key=r HTTP/1.1
Host: www.hi-tier.de
Accept: application/json
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2023 08:06:51 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 334

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I have tested the same request using ReqBin and directly in my browser (Google Chrome), and it returns the expected response of "HIT3 Version 3.1.20230424". However, when I try to send the request in Postman, I receive the "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname" error.

I have checked the URL, proxy settings, and SSL configurations in Postman, but I'm unable to resolve the issue. Are there any additional settings or configurations that I might be missing? I would appreciate any suggestions or insights to help me troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

[image: Postman screenshot]

Comment: Hi @NotGael, You may retry after disabling SSL verification in Postman settings and inform if it resolves your issue. Additionally, you may set the Accept header in your request to */* instead of application/json.